# AngularJS bind specific data to template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, angularjs

I'm currently making a switch from Knockout to Angular. The main problem I'm having right now is in transferring my original templates to something Angular will recognise.

Specifically, here's a bit of code I'm having trouble transferring:

`<!-- ko template: { name: 'SquareTempl', data: Squares[5] } --><!-- /ko -->`

In Knockout, this will attach Squares[5] to SquareTempl, so that when the template gets rendered, it does so using the members within Squares[5](or whatever data that gets attached).

I need to repeat the process for Squares[0]~Squares[11]. I can't use ng-repeat though since I won't be iterating through them in numerical order.

Ideally, it would be nice if I could do something along the lines of

`<td class="Square" id="five" ng-include src="'SquareTempl.html'" ng-data="Squares[5]">`

Any ideas?

Here's a JSFiddle I've written to outline a failed attempt I've tried using ng-model.

http://jsfiddle.net/fZz3W/9/

Comment: did you try `ng-model`?

Comment: @Tyrsius I'm not sure what you mean exactly. `ng-model` instead of the fake `ng-data` I put up in my example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @Tyrsius I've just tried, but I don't seem to be getting any luck. I think I'll post up an example for people to fiddle around with. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

Two things: First, you can make ng-data be available by implementing it yourself `YourApp.directive("ngData", function() {})` Secondly, do you need the HTML to be part of another file? An easy way to accomplish what you're looking for in Angular is with `ng-repeat` like:

```
<td ng-repeat="item in Square">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div> 
</td>
```

When the `Square` array is updated an additional post will be made.

Review your modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TdWMF/1/

So this is mostly a hack to achieve what you want, until I can offer you a better solution:

Second update using mixed order `ng-repeat`: http://jsfiddle.net/TdWMF/3/

Basically:

```
<div ng-repeat="index in [4, 2, 0, 3, 1]">
   square index: {{index}}<br />
   square: {{Squares[index]}}
</div>
```

Pretty ugly, and non-ideal, I know. I'd also recommend performing the order array generate in a function and then doing: `ng-repeat="index in displayOrder(Squares)"`

Comment: I don't necessarily need the html to be in another file, but I can't use ng-repeat since I'm not rendering through the items in numerical order as I've stated above. I'll start looking into custom directives, but if you could, it would be nice if you could show me an example; I'm still having trouble getting my head around the basics of angularjs.

Comment: @dk123 If you aren't rendering them in order why use an array? Or, order them in the order you want to render them. Also, review the answer again I reformatted your original fiddle to use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @dk123 I also apologize, I didn't notice the clause where you stated you couldn't use `ng-repeat` that's on me.

Comment: It's fine. I know you're just trying to help. I'm using an array because I want to render the same kind of objects. I could just order them in the way I wanted to without using templates, but the JSFiddle's just a simplified example. My actual SquareTempl.html has about 30lines of html. It would just be horrific to render all those without using templates.

Comment: @dk123 The biggest benefit of Angular is that HTML becomes your template, feel free to use it. I've posted a secondary fiddle and a hack to get the effect you're looking for (based on my understanding) with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @dk123 In the hack, if you need to access the render order you still have the magic `$index` available to you which would be in the current index in the display order array, while the `index` (badly named) loop value is the index of the square to display for that template.

Comment: +1 for the neat use of indexes. I'll definitely be using that in some other part of the page. It isn't optimal though as it doesn't solve the fact that I'll have to paste in similar bits of html if for example there's an anomaly that interrupts during the index rendering (please see updated JSFiddle). Thanks though, I'll definitely be accepting this if I find no other method.

Comment: @dk123 If that is the case then I fear I don't know enough about your case to give you much more help. I do hope someone comes along and gives you a good anser though

Comment: Thanks, it's great knowing that people like you are here wanting to give help.